# Migrating from Telegram's getUpdate to using webhooks in a bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram, webhooks

I have problem with a webhook in a Telegram bot! I have a form for give token for my telegram bot , and answer to my bot According to token insert in form. When I use get update method, everything is good, but when I use web hook, don't work! My URL has an SSL certificate, web hook is set.

```
$botToken = $_POST['token'];
//$botToken = json_decode($botToken, TRUE);
$webSite = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$chatId = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

$message = strtolower($message);
switch ($message) {

 case "/start":
 sendMessage($chatId, "start!م");
 break;
 case "hi":
 sendMessage($chatId, "hiii");
 break;
 case "khubi":
  sendMessage($chatId, "bad nistam!");
  break;
 case "che khabar":
  sendMessage($chatId, "salamati");
  break;
 default:
 sendMessage($chatId, "chi migi ??");
 // sendMessage($chatId, "$chatId");

}
function sendMessage($chatId, $message)
{
 $url = $GLOBALS['webSite'] . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatId . "&text=" . urlencode($message);
 file_get_contents($url);
}
```

The problem is when I use web-hook and I post token don't work, but when I use web-hook and I store token in a variable, it work correctly. 
I really do not know why it does not work, I've tried everything!!!!
Please give me guidance, How can I solve this? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: can you share sample json that is posted to this file ?

Comment: string(73) "https://api.telegram.org/bot434441867:AAFIcipstLlbLZ0NXFU4j8RA6wB02mkftUM"

Comment: you can do json_encode your token and post to this file and you can get the same in `file_get_contents("php://input");` and `json_decode` the same.

Comment: string(45) "434441867:AAFIcipstLlbLZ0NXFU4j8RA6wB02mkftUM"

Comment: I use json encode , but it don't work !!!!

Comment: can you show the code how you encoding and posting the token to this file ?

Comment: <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="robot_api">robot API Token:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="token" placeholder="robot API Token" name="token" style="width: 500px;">
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div> -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>

Comment: I  post token , and encode with json , It don't work ,  but when I store token in a variable , It work corectly !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you can use both `$_POST and file_get_contents('php://input')` i guess, you have to either hardcode token inside the file or you need send the `json_encoded` token directly to your file.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram Bot Webhook **won't** POST Token to your server, but you can make it to a part of webhook URL. e.g., `https://www.sean.taipei/telegram/hook.php?token=12345:AAJqs_w-4`

If above solution didn't work, you can find out problem via the following method:

Check [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) method, make sure your webhook URL is correct, and no `last_error_message` field.

POST similar data to your server, [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) is some data you can use in `curl -d JSON`, just copy it and run on your own server.

At last, check your CDN config (if you had applied on that server), temporary disable flooding or any check.

Comment: I did all this, but did not get the result, I am really looking for this, but I don't Know what is error???

Answer (score 1):

I have some general suggestions for debugging may these help you:

1. Use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to post a manual message like Telegram webhook message structure to make sure there are no bugs in your controller.

sample:

```
{
    "update_id":10000,
    "message":{
      "date":1441645532,
      "chat":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "message_id":1365,
      "from":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "text":"/start"
    }
```

[image: Postman]

2. to make sure Telegram is sending any message you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and create an https proxy to your localhost.

Use this command in ngrok:

```
ngrok http 20201
```

20201 is your localhost port (localhost:20201).
Now ngrok give you an https link, and you must set that link as your telegram webhook (just like the way you said).
At this moment if Telegram sends a webhook message for your bot then you can debug it in the localhost.

3. Finally, if you do not find the problem you must read the [Marvin's Patent Pending Guide to All Things Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks) to check all the requirements again.

> 1. Supports IPv4, IPv6 is currently not supported for Webhooks.
> 2. Accepts incoming POSTs from 149.154.167.197-233 on port 443,80,88 or 8443.
> 3. Is able to handle TLS1.0+ HTTPS-traffic.
> 4. Provides a supported,non-wildcard, verified or self-signed certificate.
> 5. Uses a CN or SAN.that matches the domain you’ve supplied on setup.
> 6. Supplies all intermediate certificates to complete a verification chain.

Answer (score -1):

for someone who need to run / debug telegram bot on localhost, maybe you can use this npm package.

https://github.com/qutek/telehook

just install it as a global package on your machine using
`npm install -g telehook`

and then run the command
`telehook run your-bot:token-key http://localhost/your-hook`